# Raspbian missing modules in lsmod output

Tags: raspbian, kernel, modules

when I type lsmod I get the output below. But I am missing all the other but the sound modules. Why are no other modules shown?
I am using the latest Raspbian release (12/16/12)

```
root@raspberrypi:~# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_bcm2835            12808  0 
snd_usb_audio          93242  0 
snd_pcm                74834  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_bcm2835
snd_page_alloc          4951  1 snd_pcm
snd_hwdep               5730  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_usbmidi_lib        17812  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_seq_midi            4518  0 
snd_seq_midi_event      6453  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            20611  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_usbmidi_lib
snd_seq                52536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              19698  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd_seq_device          6300  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd                    52489  9           
snd_seq_device,snd_timer,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_usbmidi_lib, snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_usb_audio,snd_bcm2835
```

Comment: What more modules were you expecting? lsmod only shows the currently loaded modules, not the available modules. So as long as there is no process that uses a certain module (i2c for example) it will not be loaded and thus not be shown in lsmod.

Comment: I am missing modules for the ethernet or graphics module for example.

Comment: My guess on those two modules is that they are directly compiled into the kernel being non-removable from the print anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably mixing lsmod with modprobe.

```
man lsmod:

lsmod is a trivial program which nicely formats the contents of the /proc/modules,
showing what kernel modules are currently loaded.

man modprobe:

-l --list List  all  modules  matching the given wildcard (or "*" if no wildcard is given).
```